# Get distance between screen edge and webpage

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, add-in

[image]

Ok, consider this image.

```
I develop an IE extension in c# and I would :
  - the distance in red, between top of screen and top of `visible webpage`
  - the distance in red between left of screen and left of `visible webpage`
  - the width/heigth of the visible webpage
```

Of course considering that i have the whole screen size. If i have red and black I can calculate green.

What the point ?

I have thousand screen coordinates (X,Y), i have to calcul the coordinate relative to the webpage.

```
Example : 

Considering
  Screen size : 1200 * 800
  Webpage size : 400*300
  Red distance between left screen border and left webpage border  : 200
  Red distance between top screen border and top webpage border  : 300

So my coordinates screen => relative webpage becomes :
  ( 100, 100 ) => OUTSIDE WEBPAGE( ignored )
  ( 1100, 650 ) => OUTSIDE WEBPAGE ( ignored )
  ( 200, 300 ) => ( 0,0 )
  ( 250, 400 ) => ( 50, 100 )
```

Actually i have this code, `this` is inherited from `AddinExpress.IE.ADXIEModule`, thetoolbarObj is the toolbar that I added to InternetExplorer. So i can use pointToScreen on it and i'm not far of what I need, but the left corner of the toolbar is not what I need, I need the leftcorner of the webpage.

```
public void getUtilsDimension()
{
    Rectangle resolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    Int32 screenWidth = resolution.Width;
    Int32 screenHeight = resolution.Height;

    AddinExpress.IE.ADXIEToolBarItem toolbarItem = this.ToolBars[0];
    AddinExpress.IE.ADXIEToolbar toolbarObj = toolbarItem.ToolBarObj;
    Point leftCornerWebPage = toolbarObj.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
    Int32 toolbarHeight = toolbarObj.Height;
    Int32 toolbarWidth = toolbarObj.Width;

    Debug.WriteLine("Largeur écran : " + screenWidth);
    Debug.WriteLine("Hauteur écran : " + screenHeight);
    Debug.WriteLine("LeftCornerX : " + leftCornerWebPage.X);
    Debug.WriteLine("LeftCornerY : " + leftCornerWebPage.Y);
    Debug.WriteLine("toolbarHeight : " + toolbarHeight);
    Debug.WriteLine("toolbarWidth : " + toolbarWidth);

}
```

This is what I get actually, the screen is 1600*900, pointToScreen return the coordinates of the red cross ( 484,158 ). But I need the coordinates of the blue cross, as the width and heigh of visible webpage. I know I can get that with $(window) in Jquery, but i don't know how with c#.

I can access at the HTLMDocument (typeof `mshtml.HTMLDocument`) with `this.HTMLDocument`, unfortunately pointToScreen is not available on HTMLDocument object.

[image]

Edit : It s chrome on the first screenshot but of course that should be IE

**Update 08/12**

OK I have the width and height of the visible webpage ( black line on my screen shot )
The only missing thing is the coordinates of blue cross on my screenshot 2

```
var heightVisibleWebPage = HTMLDocument.documentElement.offsetHeight;
var widthVisibleWebPage = HTMLDocument.documentElement.offsetWidth;
```

For the bounty, I need the exact coordinates of the blue cross. No matter how. It should work no matter the Internet explorer version, favorites/tool/command/state bar displayed or not.

**Update 08/12 HTMLDocument**

`HTMLDocument` is from AddinExpress, it's not a `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument`

```
public mshtml.HTMLDocument HTMLDocument
{
    get
    {
        return (this.HTMLDocumentObj as mshtml.HTMLDocument);
    }

}
```

His parent HTMLDocument.parentWindows is a [IHTMLWindow2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object

HTMLDocumentObj is a member of

```
public class ADXIEModule : Component, IRemoteModule2, IRemoteModule, IObjectWithSite, IWin32Window
{
     ...
    //
    // Résumé :
    //     Gets the automation object (a COM object) of the active document, if any.
    //
    // Notes :
    //     When the active document is an HTML page, this property provides access to
    //     the contents of the HTML Document Object Model (DOM). Specifically, it returns
    //     an HTMLDocument object reference. The HTMLDocument object is functionally
    //     equivalent to the HTML document object used in HTML page script. It supports
    //     all the properties and methods necessary to access the entire contents of
    //     the active HTML document.
    //     The HTMLDocument object can be used through the IHTMLDocument interface,
    //     the IHTMLDocument2 interface, and the IHTMLDocument3 interface.
    //     When other document types are active, such as a Microsoft Word document,
    //     this property returns the document automation object of that document. For
    //     Word documents, this is the Document object.
    [Browsable(false)]
    public object HTMLDocumentObj { get; }

    ...
```

}

Explain when -1 for the community please ;)

Comment: The downvote was likely because you haven't shown what you have tried. The users here are here to help solve a problem with your code, not code a solution for you. Do you have code to show?

Comment: The HTMLDocument should have parentWindow field - does it return the whole IE window, or the container for the html drawing rectangle?

Comment: Unfortunately, the parentWindow is not a Windows.Forms, I edited my question with more details about HTMLDocument and AddInExpress. I'm really new with AddInExpress ^^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps:

1. Find `Internet Explorer` window handle with `EnumWindows()` api. Class name is `IEFrame`
2. Iterate through all child windows with `EnumChildWindows()` api. Class name is `Internet Explorer_Server`
3. Find `x, y` coordinate with `GetWindowRect()` api

**Code:**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWindowsCallback lpEnumFunc, int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hWndParent, EnumWindowsCallback lpEnumFunc, int lParam);

public delegate bool EnumWindowsCallback(IntPtr hwnd, int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void GetClassName(IntPtr hwnd, StringBuilder s, int nMaxCount);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
    public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
    public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
    public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

private IntPtr ieHandle, ieChildHandle;

private void GetWindows()
{
    EnumWindows(Callback, 0);
}

private bool Callback(IntPtr hwnd, int lParam)
{
    StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(256);

    GetClassName(hwnd, className, className.Capacity);

    if (className.ToString().Equals("IEFrame"))
    {
        ieHandle = hwnd;

        return false;
    }

    return true; //continue enumeration
}

private void GetChildWindows()
{
    if (ieHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        EnumChildWindows(ieHandle, CallbackChild, 0);
    }
}

private bool CallbackChild(IntPtr hwnd, int lParam)
{
    StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(256);

    GetClassName(hwnd, className, className.Capacity);

    if (className.ToString().Equals("Internet Explorer_Server"))
    {
        ieChildHandle = hwnd;

        return false;
    }

    return true; //continue enumeration
}
```

*To get the coordinates:*

```
GetWindows();
GetChildWindows();

if (ieChildHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    RECT rect;

    if (GetWindowRect(ieChildHandle, out rect))
    {
        //rect.Left, rect.Top
    }

}

ieChildHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
ieHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
```

*Tested with IE 6, 9 and 11*

Comment: It's a very interesting approach! But my custom Toolbar (IE Extension) creates some bug and your code gives the position of my hidden addinexpress toolbar (http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=213155Result.jpg ) we can see on the screenshot a strange texture. But without my custom toolbar it works. Unfortunately I can't unactivate my toolbar because it's a part of my IE Extension. So if no one post a better answer I'll accept yours this week.

Comment: @amdev Add a list `private List<IntPtr> childHandles = new List<IntPtr>();`. Remove `ieChildHandle = hwnd; return false;` from `if (className.ToString().Equals("Internet Explorer_Server"))` and add `childHandles.Add(hwnd);` instead. Dont forget to remove `return false;`! After `GetWindows(); GetChildWindows();` check `childHandles.Count`.

Comment: Ok childHandles[1] is what I need ! Thanks, great approach, great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get a handle on the current tab:

```
foreach (InternetExplorer ie in new ShellWindows())
{
    // Find
    // Current
    // Tab
    //currentTab.left // left edge in pixels
}
```

You may need to drill down into parent objects using ".parent" to add all the the offsets needed until you get the total offset of the browser tab.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx#properties